# How to join multiple tables mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

- orderItems(orderItemsNo, orderID, menuItemNo, amount)
- order (orderID, orderDate, branchID)
- menuItem(menuItemNo, item-name, price, description, menuGroup)
- menuGroup(menuGrpNo, grp-name, grp-descr)

I'm trying to list the `order`s and `menuItem`s that have been ordered between `2012-02-01` and `2012-04-30`. I need to display the menu items information - even those that were not ordered by any customer during the period. (In those cases, the `orderID` will be `NULL`.)

The result should be like this:

```
orderID, item-name, grp-name
```

Comment: What have tried to achieve the desired output?

Comment: So what have you tried? Please refer to http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: This is a basic query that involves joins and conditions. Please give it a go and post questions with specific problems first rather than asking for code.

Comment: Sorry but I am very new in stackoverflow and mysql. I do have it a try, my query. SELECT orderID AS 'Order ID', `item-name` AS 'Menu Item Name', `grp-name` AS 'Menu Item Group' FROM orderItems o, menuItem mI, menuGroup mG WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `order` 
WHERE orderID = o.orderID AND orderDate between '2015-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-11-30 00:00:00' AND o.menuItemNo = mI.menuItemNo and mI.menuGrpNo = mG.menuGrpNo) ORDER BY orderID; but it doesn't ouput as i wanted it to be..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This most likely won't work since I have very little information to go on but you're probably looking for a query somewhat like this:

```
SELECT
    `order`.orderID, menuItem.`item-name`, menuGroup.`grp-name`
FROM
    menuItem
    JOIN menuGroup ON
        menuGroup.menuGrpNo = menuItem.menuGroup
    LEFT JOIN orderItems ON
        orterItems.menuItemNo = menuItem.menuItemNo
    LEFT JOIN `order` ON
        `order`.orderID = orterItems.orderID AND
        `order`.orderDate BETWEEN '2012-02-01' AND '2012-04-30'
```

Try to understand how this works and work it into a solution for your problem. In particular read up on the [different types of joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) and how to select from multiple tables.

Also, avoid using reserved keywords (such as 'order') for table or field names.